# What does the := operator mean in mysql?

Tags: mysql, operators, rank, colon-equals

I have a `mysql` table (`scho_id`,`school_name`,`school_views`).

I was looking for a `mysql` query to get `rank` of schools on the basis of `school_views`.

I found this solution on stackoverflow.

```
SET @points := -1, @num := 0;
SELECT scho_id
, school_views
, @num := if(@points = school_views, @num, @num + 1) as school_rank
, @points := school_info.school_views as dummy
FROM school_info
ORDER BY school_views desc, scho_id asc;
```

This solved my problem but I notice a new operator `:=` in this query. I am curious to know the meaning and uses of this operator.

Comment: If you simply check the mysql docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) you will see that..... they're wrong. Nice.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In MySQL, `:=` is an assignment operator:

```
SELECT @foo := 'bar';    // variable 'foo' now has value 'bar'
return value: 'bar'
```

while `=` is an equality test:

```
SELECT @foo = 'hi mom'; // does variable 'foo' have the value 'hi mom';
return value: false   ('bar' == 'hi mom' -> false)
```

Note that you CAN do both equality testing AND assignment with `set` queries:

```
SET @foo = 'bar' = 'baz';
```

which will cause `@foo` to be assigned `false`, the boolean result of `'bar' = 'baz'`. It executes as the following:

```
SET @foo = ('bar' = 'baz');
SET @foo = false;
```

Comment: So the `=` (equality test operator ) work as assignment operator if it is used with `SET` ?
E.g - `SET @param='some value'`  and  with `UPDATE` statement e.g. `UPDATE table_name SET column_name='value'`

Comment: yes. the first `=` in a `set` does assignment. a set query can't return anything, so it doesn't make much sense to have `=` do an equality test. the result of that test couldn't be returned. however, now that this will do testing AND assignment: `set @foo = 'bar' = 'baz';`. `@foo` will be assignment the boolean result of the `'bar' = 'baz'` equality test, e.g. false.

Comment: It seem though, you cannot use := with declared variables in SELECT statements.

Comment: explained very well. thanks